# Setting up multiple emulators on Android Eclipse

Tags: android, emulation

I am running a performance test for my android application, want to know whether it is possible to run multiple emulators at once in Eclipse?

If yes, how do i go about doing it?

Comment: launch them from the adb

Comment: In order to setup multiple emulators, you have to setup multiple emulators. :)

Comment: For Emulator check this link: http://wisdomitsol.com/Blog/Android/Make-Android-Environment/Setting-Up-Emulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Create multiple emulators
- Change android project run configuration, target as manual selection instead of auto.
- Right click on android project -> Run As -> Run Configuration. 
  On Run configuration window select the project under Android application [at right panel]
        Then select Target tab at left panel, and select manual option. that all..

Now whenever you run that selected project, the eclipse will pop up the window with list of running emulators and devices..

To run more than one emulator
1. Open AVD manager
2. select emulator
3. click on start -> launch

Answer (score 1):

You can run multiple emulators by just calling run again, then in the panel "Android Device Chooser" you can choose another Android Virtual Device. To add new Android Virtual Devices to your Android virtual device manager, just click the device manager button on the bar at the top of eclipse, then in the next screen click new and create a new virtual device. The virtual devices go kind of slowly if there are many of them, but you can use multiple emulators this way.

Answer (score 1):

Open AVD Manager. Create multiple AVD/emulator and run them.
Got to the link for help http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/index.html