# How to run multiple android emulators?

Tags: android, shell, command-line, emulation, android-virtual-device

I just started learning the Android SDK and I'm trying to run another emulator via command line. When I run the command:

```
android emulator -avd sender
```

from C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools, I get the following error.

```
Error: Expected verb after global parameters but found 'emulator' instead.
```

I actually got it to work once. I have already created an AVD called sender via AVD manager..

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
emulator.exe -avd sender
```

from command line in C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools.

This will tell the emulator.exe to open android virtual device "sender", assuming that you already created one virtual device called *sender*.

Comment: You sir, are my hero. In case anyone else runs into this issue. You do not need to put "Android" in front of the emulator.exe -avd sender. Why is it that I have to put exe though?

Comment: I think there might be something wrong with the most updated AVD Manager: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332012/avd-manager-cant-run-multiple-emulators-any-more. I found a work around by manually selecting an AVD in eclipse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306581/setting-up-multiple-emulators-on-android-eclipse. Your answer helped to from command line, but didn't work when trying to open multiple AVDs. Thanks~